# Native web-app detecting phone activity

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, web-applications, mobile

I’m building a web site which will also work as a native web-app using mostly client side technologies.

I was wondering if there is a way to detect a mobile activity using javascript or any other client side trick?

My goal is to be able to stop playing a video while the user answers his call or responds to his text message.

If not through client side then is there a way to do this without having the user install my app?

Thanks a bunch
Moshe S.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "native web-app"?  Native to *what*?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the phone will itself stop any and all unnecessary activity like videos when a call comes in. At least iOS does.

Comment: @deceze Android also does, I also think that pretty much every phone will pause your application. If I'm not completely wrong, jqm + phonegap has an event for "on app pause" you can use to stop it manually.

Comment: Hi 
By ‘native web-app’ I mean:  a web site that dedicated to smartphones.  For iOS users I’m giving the option to bookmark it to their home screen. Allowing them to access the web site through the shortcut and having the web site behave like an application.